# To show a dense subspace of lp(Z)?

Tags: functional-analysis

Exercise:

[image]

### My proposal

Recall that

\begin{equation}
 \|u\|_p
 :=  \left( \sum\limits_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} | u_{j} |^{p} \right)^{1/p}, 
 \,\,\, 
 j \in \mathbb{Z}, 
 \forall u = \left( u_{j} \right) \in l_{p},
 \,  
 u_{j} \neq 0 
 \, \text{ if } 1 \leq p < \infty,
\end{equation}

Let $u \in l^{p}(\mathbb{Z})$, $V \subset l^{p}(\mathbb{Z})$, and let $\{v_{j}\}_{j}$ be a sequence in $V$ which converges to $u$. The countable union of closed set is closed in $\mathbb{Z}$ when $u_{j} \neq 0$. (unsure about this step!) Because $V$ has finite dimension, we have a basis $\{ u_{1}, ..., u_{k} \}$ of $V$. Also, $u \in$ Span$(u_{1}, ..., u_{k}, u)$. But, we have that $V$ is closed in Span$(u_{1}, ..., u_{k}, u)$ with $v_{n} \to u$, and then $u \in V. \square$

### Svetoslav's answer rewritten

Recall that
$$ V=\left\{u\in l^p(\mathbb Z): \left\{j\in\mathbb Z:u_j\neq 0\right\} \text{is finite}\right\}\subset l^p(\mathbb Z)$$ where 
$$\|u\|_p
 :=  \left( \sum\limits_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} | u_{j} |^{p} \right)^{1/p}, 
 \,\,\, 
 \forall \,u = \left\{ u_{j} \right\}_{j\in\mathbb Z} \in l_{p},\,\, 1 \leq p < \infty. $$

Let an element be $u \in l^{p}(\mathbb{Z})$, and a sequence of elements $(v^{j})_{j=1}^{\infty}\subset V$. 
The series 
\begin{equation*}
||u||_{p}^{p} = \sum\limits_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} |u_{j}|^{p} < \infty,
\end{equation*}
is (absolutely) convergent which implies that its tail tends to zero. Indeed, 
let $S_n := \sum\limits_{j\in\mathbb Z,j\leq |n|} |u_{j}|^{p}$ be the partial sums of the series and let $A=\sum\limits_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} |u_{j}|^{p} < \infty$ be its sum. 
By the definition for convergent series, given $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have 
\begin{equation*}
|\sum_{ |j| > n } |u_{j}|^{p} |=|A-S_n| < \epsilon.   
\end{equation*}
implying $\sum_{ |j| > n } |u_{j}|^{p} \to 0$, when $n \to \infty$. 
Take for approximating sequence $\{ v^{j} \}_{j=1}^{\infty} \subset V$: 
\begin{equation*}
v^{j} = (0,0, ..., 0, u_{-j}, u_{-j+1}, ..., u_{-1}, u_{0}, u_{1}, ..., u_{j-1}, u_{j}, 0, 0, ...) \in V 
\end{equation*}
and see that this sequence converges to $u$, i.e
\begin{equation*}
|| v^{j} - u ||_{p}=\sum_{ |k| > j } |u_{k}|^{p} \to 0 \, \text{ when } \, j \to \infty. 
\end{equation*}

Therefore $V$ is a dense subspace of $l^{p}(\mathbb{Z})$ for $1 \leq p < \infty. \square$

How can you show better that V is a dense subspace of $l^{p}(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: $V$ is not finite dimensional .

Comment: And your proposal is completely messed up :) You should show that for an arbitrary $u\in l^p(\mathbb Z)$ there is a sequence $\{v_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}\subset V$ such that $\|v_j-u\|_{l^p}\rightarrow 0$ when $j\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: How can you say that? Is the following right? *The countable union of closed set is closed in $\mathbb{Z}$ when $u_{j} \neq 0$*. There is no limit point of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

**Notation:** An element $u\in l^p(\mathbb Z)$ is a sequence $\{u_j\}_{j\in\mathbb Z}$ (with subscript) and a sequence of elements in $l^p(\mathbb Z)$ we denote with superscript: $\left\{v^k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$

Because $\|u\|_p^p=\sum\limits_{j\in\mathbb Z}{|u_j|^p}<\infty$ (absolutely convergent series) then the tail of this series tends to $0$, i.e $\sum\limits_{|j|>n}{|u_j|^p}\rightarrow 0$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$. Then take for approximating sequence $\{v^j\}\subset V$ :
$$v^j=(0,0,...,0,u_{-j},u_{-j+1},..,u_{-1},u_0,u_1,..,u_{j-1},u_{j},0,0,.. )\in V$$
and see that $\|v^j-u\|_p\rightarrow 0$ when $j\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Where do you fix *n* first time? You take *j* amount of elements. Then, you say that this amount is absolutely bigger than *n*. What is this *n*?

Comment: I take summation over all indices $j\in\mathbb Z$ such that $|j|>n$. This means all indices $j\in\mathbb Z$ without $j=0, \pm 1, \pm 2,...,\pm n $.

Comment: For $n=1, 2, 3,... $ this summation gives the sequence of tails for our series.

Comment: I rewrote the proof based on your answer to the body of the question. Can it be made more rigorous?

Comment: I made an edit to your question in the part where you remade my answer. I think now it is much more clear.

Comment: I extended the challenge to the domain from real numbers here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1436315/17474 but it seems to be rather similar. However, not so sure.

Comment: Everything seems be to ok! I was thinking why the tail of this series tends to zero and if that I could make the explanation more rigorous.

Comment: Because for every convergent series, the tail tends to zero. Here is a link 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192529/why-does-the-tail-a-na-n1a-n2-ldots-of-convergent-series-sum-a-n-te

Comment: Thank you! I clarified the part in the body of the question by using epsilon-n -thing explicitly. Better?

Comment: I edited the answer in the body of your question, so when it is peer-review you will see it.