# Show strong but not norm convergence on $L^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

The task:

let $1 \le p < \infty$ and $A_k : L^p (\Bbb R) \to L^p (\Bbb R)$ such that $(A_k u) (x) = u(x+\frac 1 k)$. Show that $\| A_k u - u\|_p \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ (for all $u \in L^p (\Bbb R)$), but that $\| A_k - I \| \not\to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ (in other words, $A_k$ converges strongly to $I$, but not in norm).

I think I managed to do the first part rather weakly by mimicking this one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1434970/17474) but I am interested in how you can show rigorously that $|| A_{k} - I || \not\to 0$.

### My draft proposal to whole task

Recall that 
\begin{equation*}
A_{k} u(x) := u \left( x + \frac{1}{k} \right), 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
|| u ||_{p} := \left( \sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb{Z} } | u_{k} |^{p} \right)^{1/p}, \, \forall u = \{ u_{k} \}_{k \in \mathbb{Z} } \in l_{p}, \, 1 \leq p < \infty.  
\end{equation*}

Let an element be $u \in l^{p}(\mathbb{R})$, 
and a sequence of elements $(v^{k})_{k=1}^{\infty} \subset l^{p}(\mathbb{R})$. 
The series 
\begin{equation*}
||u||_{p}^{p} = \sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} |u_{k}|^{p} < \infty,
\end{equation*}
is (absolutely) convergent which implies that its tail tends to zero:
\begin{equation*} 
\sum_{ |k| > n } |u_{k}^{p}| \to 0 \, \text{ when } \, n \to \infty.
\end{equation*}
Take for approximating sequence $\{ A^{k} \}_{k=1}^{\infty} := \{ v^{k} \}_{k=1}^{\infty} \subset l^{p}(\mathbb{R}):$
\begin{equation*}
v^{k} = (0,0, ..., 0, u_{-k}, u_{-k+1}, ..., u_{-1}, u_{0}, u_{1}, ..., u_{k-1}, u_{k}, 0, 0, ...) \in l^{p}( \mathbb{R} )
\end{equation*}
and see that the sequence converges to $u$ for all $u \in L^{p}(\mathbb{R})$:
\begin{equation*}
|| v^{k} - u ||_{p} = \sum\limits_{ |n| > k } | u_{n} |^{p} \to 0 \, \text{ when } \, k \to \infty, 
\end{equation*}
Thus $||A_{k} u - u ||_{p} \to 0$ as $k \to \infty. \, \square$

Consider the tail of the mapping when $n = k$: 
\begin{align*}
|| A_{k} - I ||_{p} &= || u \left( x + \frac{1}{k} \right) - I || \\
&= ||  \frac{u \left( x + 1/k \right)^{2} - u(x + 1/k)}{ u(x + 1/k) } || \not\to 0 
\, \text{ when } \, k \to \infty,
\end{align*}
because $u(x + 1/k) \neq 0.$  $A_{k}$ converges strongly to $I$, but not in norm. $\square$

Comments:

- I think $A_{k} u(x)$ means the $k$-th term. Does it?
- Taking a sequence in the domain but not in the subset of the domain worries me

### Rewritten Martini's answer

Recall that 
\begin{equation*}
A_{k} u(x) := u \left( x + \frac{1}{k} \right), 
\end{equation*}
To prove strong convergence, the space of continuous maps with the compact support, $C_c(\mathbb{R})$, is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$. 
For the element $u \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$, $| u - u_{k} |$ is bounded above by an integrable function (reverse Fatou lemma): $\| u - A_{k} u \|$ is bounded by $2\|u\|_{\infty} \cdot 1_{\text{supp} \, u+(-1,1)},$ where $1_{A}$ denotes the characteristic function of a set $A$, and 
\begin{equation*}
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sup \int_{\mathbb{R}} | u - u_{k}| 
\leq \int_{S} \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sup | u - u_{n} | d\mu = 0,
\end{equation*}
which implies that the limit exists and vanishes:
\begin{equation*}
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} | u - u_{n} | d\mu = 0.
\end{equation*}
which implies that by the *dominated convergence theorem*:
\begin{equation*}
|| A_k u - u ||_p^p = 
\int_{\mathbb{R}} | u\left(x + \frac{1}{k} \right) - u(x) |^p \, dx \to 0, \qquad k \to \infty
\end{equation*}
where the continuity of $u$ gives the pointwise convergence of the integrand.
... (rest in Martini's answer)

Comments:

- the first part of the proof have some things about which I am not sure
- the second part is ok by the proof of contradiction

---

How can you show that $A_{k}$ does not converge strongly to $I$ in the norm?

Comment: i think you mixed some things up: why do you use $\ell^p$ in your draft? in the question it is all about $L^p$.

Comment: Nooo :) This $L^p(\mathbb R)$ is totally different space. It is the space of all  functions (more precisely, classes of functions) $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $\|f\|_p=\left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}{|f(x)|^p dx}\right)^{1/p}$. These are Lebesgue integrable functions.

Comment: I advise you to read the book you are reading from the very beginning !

Comment: The last sentence in your question is also problematic: we have strong convergence, we have convergence in the norm, they are different, but you mix them in *"$A_k$ does not converge strongly to $I$ in the norm"*.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**.
$A_k u$ is by definition the map $x \mapsto u(x + 1/k)$ (where $u \colon \mathbf R \to \mathbf R$ is a given measurable, $p$-integrable map). You only have a sequence of maps $A_k \colon L^p(\def\R{\mathbf R}\R) \to L^p(\R)$ here, neither the domain nor its subsets consist of sequences, $L^p(\R)$ is the space of $p$-integrable maps $\R \to \R$. Do not confuse it with $\ell^p$, which consists of sequences.

To prove strong convergence, recall that $C_c(\R)$, the space of continuous maps with compact support, is dense in $L^p(\R)$. For $u \in C_c(\R)$, use the dominated convergence theorem to show that 
$$ \|A_k u - u\|_p^p = \int_{\R} \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\abs{u\left(x + \frac 1k \right) - u(x)}^p\, dx \to 0, \qquad k\to \infty $$
(the continuity of $u$ gives pointwise convergence of the integrand).
  For arbitrary $u \in L^p(\R)$, given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $v \in C_c(\R)$ with $\|u - v\|_p < \epsilon$. As, by translation invariance of the integral $\|A_k u - A_k v\|_p = \|u - v\|_p$, we have
$$ \|u - A_k u\|_p \le 2\epsilon + \|v- A_k v\|_p $$
and the latter converges to zero.

To disprove norm convergence, note that for any $k \in \mathbf N$, there is a function $u \in L^p(\R)$ such that $u$ and $A_k u$ have disjoint support and $\|u\|_p = 1$. For example, let $u = k^{1/p}\chi_{[0,\frac 1k)}$. We have
$$ \|A_k - I\|_p \ge \|A_k u - u\|_p = 2\|u\|_p = 2 $$

---

Addendum: If you want to avoid using the dominated convergence theorem, you can argue as follows: Let $u \in C_c(\R)$ and $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Choose $M > 0$ such that $u(x) = 0$ for $x \not\in [-M,M]$. As $u$ is uniformly continuous (as it has compact support), choose $\delta > 0$ such that $|x- y| < \delta$ implies $|u(x) - u(y)| < {\epsilon}/{(2M+2)^{1/p}}$. For $k > \frac 1\delta$, we have
$$ \|{A_k u - u}\|^p_p = \int_{\R} \abs{u\left(x+\frac 1k\right)-u(x)}^p\, dx
\le \int_{-M-1}^{M+1} \frac{\epsilon^p}{2M+2}\, dx = \epsilon^p $$
that is $\|A_k u - u\|_p \le \epsilon$.

Comment: Can be done, added something.

Comment: I am thinking what is the integrable function in this part *For the element $u \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$, $| u - u_{k} |$ is bounded above by an integrable function (reverse Fatou lemma) and ...* where you use the reverse Fatou lemma in the proof of strong convergence. What is the integrable function?

Comment: $|u - A_k u|$ is bounded by $2\|u\|_{\infty} \cdot 1_{{\rm supp} \, u + (-1,1)}$, where $1_A$ denotes the characteristic function of a set $A$.